# How do I convert an integer to string with a specific format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, silverlight, c#-4.0

I'm working with SQL Server, I'm new to this.

I would like to convert an integer to a string with a specific format like

```
string sSuffixNoLeadingZero = sSuffixInt.ToString("##0");
```

This is the code written in C#. I would like to know how to do the conversion to string with `("##0")`. Please help me as I'm new to SQL

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes the leading zeros .

```
Select CAST(sSuffixInt AS INT) as sSuffixNoLeadingZero
```

Comment: I also want to know how to format any string that is like .ToString(000000) in C sharp to SQL then how do I do it? and does the above answer give me the format that I need i.e I want to know how do I do the format in Csharp in SQL suppose we have a string variable like string value=number.tostring("0000"); in SQL

Comment: pls reply to the above doubt @mhasan